# Parameters table and conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my current project there is a query where a set of parameters is given and I need to check those parameters against another table. Each of these parameters can be NULL and in this case has to be ignored. What I currently do is the following:

```
SELECT  t.col1,
        t.col2,
        t.col3,
        t.col4,
        t.col5,
        t.col6,
        t.col7,
        t.col8
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN #parameters p ON     (p.col1 IS NULL OR p.col1 = t.col1)
                            AND (p.col2 IS NULL OR p.col2 = t.col2)
                            AND (p.col3 IS NULL OR p.col3 = t.col3) 
                            AND (p.col4 IS NULL OR p.col4 = t.col4)
                            AND (p.col5 IS NULL OR p.col5 = t.col5)
                            AND (p.col6 IS NULL OR p.col6 = t.col6)
                            AND (p.col7 IS NULL OR b.col7 >= t.col7)
                            AND (p.col8 IS NULL OR b.col8 <= t.col8)
```

This means if the column in the parameters table is NULL it will be ignored otherwise it will be compared to the corresponding column in table1. This works but unfortunately is VERY slow. Does anybody know a better solution (other then concatenating a string query)?

Comment: Why is it slow: what does the query plan say about what is taking the time?

Comment: let try: select * from table1 t join #parameter  on (p.col1 = t.col1) union select * from table1 t join #parameter  on (p.col1 is null)

Comment: Does `#parameters` contain a single row or could it contain multiple rows?

Comment: @Richard: Since both conditions are allways verified (check for NULL AND check if the column content equals the corresponding columns content) this results in numerous tablescans, seeks, ...

Comment: @Giau Huynh: The result would be the whole content of table1, since the second query doesn't contain any condition at all

Comment: @Tanner: #parameters may also contain multiple rows

Comment: @RomanoZumbé If you are seeing table scans you need to look at your indexes. But look at the query plan to *know* what is going on. Could be you need to de-frag indexes or update statistics.

Comment: @Richard,: Indexes are not the problem. The problem is, that for every column that has a NULL in the parameters table a complete check for NULL in table1 is made. Creating Indexes for every column is also no option since table1 is huge and inserts happen often. I'm just searching for a better solution to exclude conditions whre the parameters value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have any real criteria that could be used to limit the data in your table, and that kind of structure usually never performs well. As far as I know, there's not much you can do to try to improve that.

Is any of these columns such that it is included in the parameters often (for all rows) and could limit the data a lot? You could use union to do something like this:

```
    SELECT  ...
    FROM table1 t
    INNER JOIN #parameters p ON p.col1 = t.col1 ...

    union

    SELECT  ...
    FROM table1 t
    INNER JOIN #parameters p ... where p.col1 is NULL
```

If you're lucky something like that might work.

The other option that comes to my mind is somehow iterate the rows in the #parameters table, which is probably what you meant by string concatenating. Either by building a dynamic SQL with either `or` clauses or `union` or have a temp. table maybe with `ignore dup key index` and create & run dynamic insert clauses one by one for all the rows in parameters -table.